# How do you obtain a view from a nib within a playground?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, swift, nib, nsbundle

In a typical Xcode project, you can obtain a view from a nib like this:

```
    var objects: NSArray?;
    NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("ExampleView", owner: nil,
                                       topLevelObjects: &objects)
    var view :NSView
    for obj in objects! {
        if (obj.isMemberOfClass(NSView)) {
            view = obj as NSView
        }
    }
    // view is now the NSView object obtained from the nib. Yay.
```

However, if I create a playground within the same Xcode project and attempt to obtain the view, the above code fails. In fact, `loadNibNamed:owner:topLevelObjects:` returns false, and we know that loading the nib failed.

Even if I create a standalone playground, and place the .xib file inside the Resources directory, `loadNibNamed:owner:topLevelObjects:` still returns false.

Why can't I use `loadNibNamed:owner:topLevelObjects:` to access a nib file from within a playground? What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mistake I have made is placing the .xib, and not the .nib, in the Resources directory. Once I place the correct file (the .nib file, durp) in the Resources directory, I can indeed access the view.

Comment: To generate a '.nib' file `ibtool --compile View.nib View.xib`

Comment: I think the correct syntax is: `ibtool input.xib --compile output.nib`